# Kamailio routing from DID to user

Tags: kamailio

I am working in scenario where External DID is mapped for a specific internet User account in Kamailio, which is stored in a MySQL table. I am able to receive Invite from DID provider and able to find the local User from DB through Kamailio DBOPS module.

We have external DIDs for each local User account.

Does this thing shall work as I want

```
$ru = "sip:" + $dbr(ra=>[0,0]) + "@" + $td  ;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The expression:

```
$ru = "sip:" + $dbr(ra=>[0,0]) + "@" + $td;
```

is changing the request URI (R-URI - the address in first line of SIP request) using the result of the SQLOPS query and the To header URI domain.

If you want to keep the R-URI domain, then use:

```
$ru = "sip:" + $dbr(ra=>[0,0]) + "@" + $rd;
```

In most of the cases R-URI domain is same as To header URI domain, but they can be different, being allowed by SIP RFC.

To answer: yes, your version should work, given the remarks above.

An alternative could be the use of **alias_db** module. It is like the query to the database, plus updating the R-URI via a single configuration function: **alias_db_lookup(...)**. It can be configured to match or not the domain part as well as update the domain part via module parameter **use_domain**.

Comment: Thanks. You have been helpful.